# Android status bar icon color selection

Tags: android

I downloaded black and white icons from [Google Material Icon](https://www.google.com/design/icons/) and I have two questions:

1. Is the color of notification bar always black in different SDK versions or device vendor themes? So I should use the white icons.
2. If not, how can I select the right icon color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1- Is the color of notification bar always Black in different SDK
>   versions or device vendor themes? So I should use the White Icons.

different vendors can change the theme to however they want. In lollipop the notification bar is not black it can me many colors and any app change change the notification bar color to fit their app color when the user is in it.

> 2- If not, how can I select the Right icon color

You should follow the [Design Guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html) on Notifications and use white icons, in lollipop your icons are automatically converted to white no matter what

Comment: Thanks. I will use the white ones, however what will happen to users in vendors which they use white status bars?

Comment: well in Android M the developer can set their app theme to declare if they use a light status bar color and it changes the color of icons, I have personally not tried it yet but you can see it here https://plus.google.com/u/0/+RomanNurik/posts/4WBSonAZxt1 as for below android M the status bar is suppose to have a darker color to prevent white on white but I dont think anything is stopping a developer from having a white status bar

Comment: I do not want to use a white bar, My concern is about users that may have devices with white bars and my notification will not be visible for them. Is it a real problem or such devices do not exists?

Comment: I understand you dont want to use a white bar, I was just pointing out what android M offers. If a manufacturer changes their theme to have a white status bar they are responsible for adjusting the notification icons since they are not following the guidelines. No such manufacturer does this AFAIK